# Having a problem displaying the correct value in the edit workorder QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to set the current value of the order_type_combo QComboBox 29: 'Complaint: Damage caused by sewer blockages' instead I'm getting a default value 2: 'Complaint: Sewerage Blockage'. These values are created in a table t_wo_workorders which uses another table wo_type as a dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QDateEdit, QComboBox, QStyleFactory, QTableView, QMessageBox, QSizePolicy, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QPalette
import psycopg2
import datetime
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDateEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


current_date = QDate.currentDate()

# Connect to the database and create a cursor object
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="mms",
    user="postgres",
    password="postgres"
)
cur = conn.cursor()

# Retrieve the last work order from the t_wo_workorders table
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM t_wo_workorders ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1")
work_order = cur.fetchone()

# Extract the values for each field in the work order
work_order_id = work_order[0]
defined = work_order[1]
org = work_order[2]
order_type = work_order[3]
scheduled = work_order[4]
status = work_order[5]
request = work_order[6]
address = work_order[7]
customer = work_order[8]
tel_no = work_order[9]




class EditWorkOrderForm(QWidget):

    def populate_org_combo(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT org_unit, id FROM org_units")
        org_units = self.cur.fetchall()
        for org_unit in org_units:
            self.org_combo.addItem(str(org_unit[0]))
            self.org_units_dict[org_unit[1]] = org_unit[0]

    def populate_order_type_combo(self, order_type):
        self.order_type = order_type
        # Retrieve the wo_type records from the database
        self.cur.execute("SELECT type_description_en, id FROM wo_type")
        wo_type = self.cur.fetchall()

        # Create a dictionary with the id values as keys and the type_description_en values as values
        self.order_types_dict = {}
        for id, type_description_en in wo_type:
            self.order_types_dict[id] = type_description_en
            self.order_type_combo.addItem(str(type_description_en))

        # Check if the order_type value is present in the order_types_dict dictionary
        if self.order_type not in self.order_types_dict:
            print("Error: Invalid order type")
            return

        # Get the index of the order_type value in the order_types_dict keys and set the combo box's current index to that value
        default_index = list(self.order_types_dict.keys()).index(self.order_type)
        self.order_type_combo.setCurrentIndex(default_index)

    def populate_status_combo(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT status_descr_en, id FROM wo_status")
        wo_status = self.cur.fetchall()
        for status in wo_status:
            self.status_combo.addItem(str(status[0]))
            self.status_dict[status[1]] = status[0]

    def __init__(self, conn, cur, order_id, defined, org, order_type, scheduled, status, request, address, customer, tel_no):
        super().__init__()
        self.cur = cur  # Assign the cur parameter to the self.cur attribute
        self.order_types_dict = {}
        self.order_type_combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.populate_order_type_combo(order_type)
        
        print(order_type)
        self.conn = conn
        self.org_units_dict = {}
        self.status_dict = {}
        self.order_id = order_id
        self.org_combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.populate_org_combo()
        if str(org) in self.org_units_dict:
            org_value = self.org_units_dict[int(org)]
        else:
            org_value = ""
        try:
            org_value = self.org_units_dict[int(org)]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        org_index = self.org_combo.findText(org_value)
        order_type_value = [v for k, v in self.order_types_dict.items() if k == order_type]
        if order_type_value:
            order_type_value = order_type_value[0]
        else:
            order_type_value = ""
        order_type_index = self.order_type_combo.findText(order_type_value)
        self.order_type_combo.setCurrentIndex(order_type_index)
        self.status_combo = QComboBox(self) 
        self.populate_status_combo()
        conn = psycopg2.connect(              
            host="localhost",
            database="mms",
            user="postgres",
            password="postgres"
        )

        self.cur.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM t_wo_workorders WHERE order_id = %s",
            (self.order_id,)
        )
        work_order = self.cur.fetchone()
        self.defined_label = QLabel("Defined:")
        self.defined_edit = QDateEdit()
        self.defined_edit.setDate(defined)

        self.org_label = QLabel("Org. Unit:")
        self.org_combo.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 25)
        self.org_combo.setCurrentIndex(int(org))
        self.org_combo.setCurrentIndex(org_index)

        self.order_type_label = QLabel("Order Type:")   
        self.order_type_combo.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 25) 
        self.order_type_combo.setCurrentIndex(int(order_type))
        self.order_type_combo.setCurrentIndex(order_type_index)

        self.scheduled_label = QLabel("Scheduled:")
        self.scheduled_edit = QDateEdit()
        self.scheduled_edit.setDate(scheduled)
        self.status_label = QLabel("Status:")
        self.status_combo = QComboBox()
        self.order_type_combo.setCurrentIndex(int(status))
        status_value = self.status_dict.get(org, "")
        status_index = self.status_combo.findText(status_value)
        self.request_label = QLabel("Request:")
        self.request_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.request_edit.setText(request)
        self.address_label = QLabel("Address:")
        self.address_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.address_edit.setText(address)
        self.customer_label = QLabel("Customer:")
        self.customer_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.customer_edit.setText(customer)
        self.tel_no_label = QLabel("Tel. No:")
        self.tel_no_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.tel_no_edit.setText(tel_no)
        self.request_gps_label = QLabel("Request GPS:") 

        layout = QVBoxLayout()  
        layout.addWidget(self.defined_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.defined_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.org_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.org_combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.order_type_label) 
        layout.addWidget(self.order_type_combo) 
        layout.addWidget(self.scheduled_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.scheduled_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.status_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.status_combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.request_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.request_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.address_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.address_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.customer_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.customer_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.tel_no_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.tel_no_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.request_gps_label)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

        def edit_work_order(self, work_order_id):
            form = EditWorkOrderForm(work_order_id)
            form.show()

        def create_edit_work_order_form(work_order_id, defined, org, order_type, scheduled, status, request, address, customer, tel_no):
            form = EditWorkOrderForm(conn, cur, work_order_id, defined, org, order_type, scheduled, status, request, address, customer, tel_no)
            return form

        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
edit_work_order_form = EditWorkOrderForm(conn, cur, work_order_id, defined, org, order_type, scheduled, status, request, address, customer, tel_no)
edit_work_order_form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and this is what it prints:

```
Error: Invalid order type
3
[Finished in 5.3s]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, but, from the look of it, it seems that you're just assigning the values in the wrong order, as the columns are probably stored differently in the database structure.

Comment: the form is not displaying which order is currently but I see that the values in the other fields are correct as they should be compared to the last order inserted on the t_wo_workorders table. I have a problem with these two fields order_type and status which are dropdowns. I also updated the code.